# How to speed up a for while loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I defined two same size vectors `t` and `coverage` in Matlab, and I need to define a third vector `n_steps`.
In particular I need to speed up the following loop:

```matlab
t = 1:100000;
coverage = double(rand(size(t)) > 0.9);

for j=1:(length(t)-1)
    n_steps(j)=0;

    while coverage(j+n_steps(j)+1)==0  && j+n_steps(j)+1<length(t)
        n_steps(j)=n_steps(j)+1;
    end
    
end
```

`t` is a time vector, and `coverage` at each time step can be 1 or 0.
For each instant `t(j)` I must find the number of time steps `n_steps(j)` to wait before the first 1 appears in the vector `coverage(j+1:length(coverage))`,

Comment: Why would you want to vectorize that loop? Do you like code that is harder to read? MATLAB loops haven't been slow in a long time. You could improve your code logic, by first extracting all the indices where `coverage` is non-zero (`find`), and then finding the first value that is larger than `j` for each `j`.

Comment: Hello Cris Luengo. I need to vectorize just because it takes long time to run. I thougth to vectorize to get it faster. I am using Matlab 2013, do you think that could be the problem?

Comment: Generally speaking you can convert `while coverage(j+index+1)==0  && j+index+1<length(t);` to a bit mask with `values = coverage(j+index+1)==0  && j+index+1<length(t);`.  I can't tell what you're doing because I don't have `t`, `index` or `coverage`.

Comment: You should ask "How can I speed up this loop?" Vectorizing sometimes makes code a bit faster, sometimes it makes it a lot slower. Vectorizing was very important prior to 2006 or so when the JIT was introduced, but it no longer is. Vectorizing for the sake of vectorizing makes it look like you're following 15-year old habits. When you write `coverage(j+index+1)`,  do you mean `coverage(j+index(j)+1)`? Did you preallocate `index`? If you give a [mre], it will be a lot easier for people to help you.

Comment: Thank you every one for the replies. I tried to give more details to the problem. Hope you can help me better now.

Comment: I have added some dummy data to make your code complete (i.e. we can copy-paste it and it runs). I don't know the characteristics of your data. `coverage` as I made it has 1/10th of its values as 1, the rest is 0. And there are 100,000 values. Please adjust to make this example match your data better. This runs in 0.01 seconds on MATLAB Online. Is this really too slow?

Answer (score 0):

Your code (with the example data I added to it) runs in 0.0163 s on MATLAB Online. Just adding

```matlab
n_steps = zeros(1,length(t)-1);
```

before the loop reduces the execution time to 0.0057 seconds. Preallocation is **very** important!

Next, I was able to change your code a bit, such that you don't need to search through the same array over and over again:

```matlab
n_steps = zeros(1,length(t)-1);
cov = [find(coverage), length(t)];
k = 1;
for j=1:(length(t)-1)
    if cov(k) <= j
        k = k+1;
    end
    n_steps(j) = cov(k) - j - 1;
end
```

This code runs in 0.0015 seconds. It relies on creating a smaller array, `cov`, that contains the indices to non-zero elements in `coverage`. `cov(k)` is the index into `coverage` for a non-zero element. As we move `j` forward, sometimes we need to move the index `k` forward too, such that `cov(k)` comes after `j`.

It might be possible to further vectorize the outer loop, but I doubt it will make the code much faster.

---

This is the script I wrote for timing and testing correctness:

```matlab
t = 1:100000;
coverage = double(rand(size(t)) > 0.9);

timeit(@() method1(t, coverage))
timeit(@() method2(t, coverage))
timeit(@() method3(t, coverage))

a = method1(t, coverage);
b = method3(t, coverage);
assert(isequal(a,b))

function n_steps = method1(t, coverage)
for j=1:(length(t)-1)
    n_steps(j)=0;
    while coverage(j+n_steps(j)+1)==0  && j+n_steps(j)+1<length(t)
        n_steps(j)=n_steps(j)+1;
    end
end
end

function n_steps = method2(t, coverage)
n_steps = zeros(1,length(t)-1);
for j=1:(length(t)-1)
    while coverage(j+n_steps(j)+1)==0  && j+n_steps(j)+1<length(t)
        n_steps(j) = n_steps(j)+1;
    end
end
end

function n_steps = method3(t, coverage)
n_steps = zeros(1,length(t)-1);
cov = [find(coverage), length(t)];
k = 1;
for j=1:(length(t)-1)
    if cov(k) <= j
        k = k+1;
    end
    n_steps(j) = cov(k) - j - 1;
end
end
```

Comment: Hello @CrisLuengo. Thank you very much for your so detailed reply. In effects I run today my original code, and it was much faster it usually was. Anyway your code is even faster, and now I am going to use it. Thank you very much again